# Como visualizar o SQL executado pelo php quando se utiliza as funções "prepare()" e "execute()"?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Olá preciso dar um echo ou print no SQL executado a partir da função abaixo. O objetivo é visualizar como o SQL ficará quando os valores de "?" forem substituídos. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

public function inserir(EmpregadoTO $empregadoTO) {

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO empregado VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";

    $connection = $this->dataSourceMySQL ->openConnection();

    try {

        $statement = $connection ->prepare($sql);


        $dia = $empregadoTO ->getDia();
        $mes = $empregadoTO ->getMes();
        $ano = $empregadoTO ->getAno();

        $dataNascimento = $ano . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dia;                        

        $statement ->bindValue(1, $empregadoTO ->getNome(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(2, $empregadoTO ->getSobrenome(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(3, $empregadoTO ->getCpf(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(4, $dataNascimento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(5, $empregadoTO ->getIdEstadoCivil(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement ->bindValue(6, $empregadoTO ->getIdEscolaridade(), PDO::PARAM_INT);            
        $statement ->bindValue(7, $empregadoTO ->getSexo(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(8, $empregadoTO ->getFoto(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(9, $empregadoTO ->getEmail(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(10, $empregadoTO ->getSenha(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(11, $empregadoTO ->getCep(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(12, $empregadoTO ->getEstado(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(13, $empregadoTO ->getCidade(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(14, $empregadoTO ->getBairro(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(15, $empregadoTO ->getTelefone(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(16, $empregadoTO ->getCelular(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement ->bindValue(17, $empregadoTO ->getNewsletterNoticia(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement ->bindValue(18, $empregadoTO ->getNewsletterVaga(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $statement ->execute();            
    }
    catch(PDOException $erro) {

        die($erro ->getTraceAsString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o [debugDumpParams();](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) ele imprime o que você quer e ainda mais coisas. Ajuda na hora de debugar os SQL.